# Prolog executable writing String in codes

Tags: prolog, native

I am trying to create an executable of following Prolog code:

```
item(one, 50, 40).
item(two, 80, 70).
item(three, 100, 55).
item(four, 50, 45).

maxMeanStudy:-  
    findall(M,item(_,M,_),L),
    max_member(Max,L),
    write("Maximum mean value:"),   % this line is not printed properly.
    writeln(Max),!.

main:-
    maxMeanStudy.
```

I am using following command to create executable as mentioned on this page: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=cmdlinecomp

```
$ swipl --goal=main --stand_alone=true -o myprog -c myques.pl
```

The executable created does not write the string "Maximum mean value:" in letters but writes it in codes:

```
$ ./myprog
[77,97,120,105,109,117,109,32,109,101,97,110,32,118,97,108,117,101,58]100
```

I am working on Linux (32bit). How can I solve this problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It looks like the `double_quotes` flag is reverted to `codes`. So your quick fix might be to either (a) include the directive, `:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, string).` at the beginning of your file, or (b) use single quotes for your strings so they are just atoms (then you don't have to worry about double quote interpretation). Of course, the best approach is (c) heed the answer @mat gave you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In almost all such cases, it turns out that:

1. **You should not use side-effects in the first place**. Instead, define **relations** that you can actually reason about. In your case, you are describing a relation between mean values and their maximum. Therefore, the name `maximum_mean_value(Ms, M)` suggests itself. And `is_that_not_more_readable` than `mixingLowerAndUpperCaseLetters`?
2. **Let the toplevel do the printing for you**, via pure queries like:

   ```
   ?- maximum_mean_value(Ms, M).
   M = ... . % result is automatically shown by the toplevel!
   ```
3. If you *really* need to write something on the terminal, do it in a **separate** predicate.
   **Avoid mixing pure and impure code.**
4. Use **`format/2`** for formatting output. For example:

   ```
   maximum_mean_value(Ms, M),
   format("Maximum mean value: ~d\n", [M])
   ```

   Note how `format/2` makes it easy to output text that involves other terms.

Comment: Perfect. It works. Which are 'pure' and 'impure' code in my code? Could you please elaborate on that a bit?

Comment: Please see **[tag:logical-purity]** for more information. If a predicate produces output on the terminal, it is *impure* (you cannot reason about terminal output within your program). If your predicate commits only to a particular solution of several possibilities, it is *impure* (other logical solutions are impurely cut away). If your predicate applies meta-logical tests like `var/1`, it is *impure*. Etc. To really benefit from logic programming, stay in the pure subset: It makes your programs very general. You can use such predicates in all directions, like: `?- maximum_mean_value(Ms, M).`.

Comment: What about `chars`?